# Multiple OR conditions in DO...WHILE loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my room booking system i have a suggest room page. It gathers all the rooms available, and then filters a few out depending on some criteria which is then stores in a variable called $RoomArray. I then randomize a room from that array and print it. This all works however if all rooms are booked i want it to to notify a user. So i am trying to use this do while loop.

```
do {
                        $RNDnum = rand(0,$roomcount-1);
                    $suggestedRoom = $RoomArray[$RNDnum];
                        $getRoomID = DB::GetInstance()->query("SELECT roomid FROM room WHERE roomname = '$suggestedRoom'");
                    $roomid = $getRoomID->results()[0]->roomid;
                    $bookingid =  Input::get('bookingdate') . Input::get('period') . $roomid;
                    $CheckIfBooked = DB::GetInstance()->query("SELECT bookingid FROM booking WHERE bookingid = '$bookingid'");

                    if($LoopCount==$roomcount-1) {
                        echo 'No rooms available';
                        $EndLoop = true;
                    }
                    $LoopCount = $LoopCount+1;
                }while (!$CheckIfBooked->count()==0 OR $EndLoop === true);
                echo $suggestedRoom;
```

However after the pages fails due to the maximum execution time i get 'No rooms available' printed. So i think there is some syntax error in my conditions.

Comment: What database framework is this? It's very important to use it effectively and have placeholder values in those queries if you can do it. Additionally `=== true` is a rather odd thing to be testing, as testing `$EndLoop` directly is more than enough.

Comment: Currently using PHP myadmin.

Comment: You're writing all this *inside* [PhpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net)? That's really a strange thing to do. It's not a framework, it's a tool for managing your database.